# dataReceived gives str not bytes error, need bytes for later decoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, construct

I have a custom protocol handler that handles incoming messages, written in python2. The data comes as encoded bytes using construct library and should be checked and passed to a construct parser down the line.

However the dataReceived function errors with "builtins.TypeError: must be str, not bytes" before it does anything else. I tried defining the data storage as empty bytearray and then adding the incoming data to it but no effect. When run independently on a python terminal the code pipeline works so I don't know what the issue is.

full trace:

```
2019-07-19 09:13:06+0300 [SimpleMessageProtocol,0,127.0.0.1] data received
2019-07-19 09:13:06+0300 [SimpleMessageProtocol,0,127.0.0.1] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 103, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 614, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 243, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/joonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 249, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/simple_message-0.0.1-py3.6.egg/simple_message/protocol.py", line 103, in dataReceived

builtins.TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

and the dataReceived function :

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    log.msg("data received")
    log.msg(data)
    self._remainingData.extend(data)
    while self._remainingData:
        try:
            self._consumeData()
        except IncompleteMessageException:
            # try again later (when we get more data)
            break
```

the project is kinda big and can be found here: https://github.com/Roiki-design/simple_message_py

**Edit**

It's solved, apparently the old logging in twisted doesn't work like i expected in python 3. the log.msg does only want strings it seems.

Comment: Is it perhaps caused by `log.msg(data)`?

Comment: Indeed it was, i apparently missed it when reading the docs that in python 3 the old logger doesn't accept bytes. I need to read more about twisted's logging it seems. Thanks.